# Do belief systems drive people to commit atrocities, or do people use belief systems as an excuse to commit atrocities?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-religion, good-and-evil, politics

Think of a random event of mass violence in history. If the perpetrators subscribed to a different religious or political belief system, would they have not committed it, because they had different beliefs, or would they have tried to justify it using their alternative beliefs?

Comment: This is also the case with the lack of belief i.e. a nihilism where killing babies is not wrong. In fact, I believe that many depraved individuals are nihilists. During WW2 the Japanese have used a variant of nihilism (inspired by DT Suzuki's Zen) to make people commit quite atrocious things.

Comment: Your question presupposes that there is a categorical answer for all perpetrators. But what makes you think that? Could not one perpetrator have acted differently with another belief system and another perpetrator not? To me this sounds like more of an empirical, (socio-)psychological question.

Comment: [False Dichotomy/False Dilemma/Black & White Fallacy?](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/black-or-white)

Comment: @bodhihammer: Actually, you cannot **make** people do things. Yes, different beliefs will result in different **outcomes**, because what people do depends on their own **free choices** as well as their environment including what others tell them (not just belief systems). But that does not mean all the choices are not free in the important aspects. In particular, a good person will try not to do evil things no matter the belief system. A bad person may not do the same evil things under a different belief system, but they will do other evil things.

Comment: @user21820 Looks like you are talking past me. Also, define 'Evil'. To use a concept of Good/Evil you have to accept those as your values, namely, that there are things that are inherently Good or Evil, but this can't be nihilism.

Comment: @bodhihammer: There is a miscommunication. I was merely saying that it's not really correct to use the word "make". I didn't imply anything about nihilism, and yes, I hold that there is a meaningful concept of inherent good and evil.

Comment: @user21820 I see what you mean. Consider then reading on Milgram's experiment that concludes that it is possible to make people do things against their will  (or moral system)  in numerous situations, using a form of authority.

Comment: @bodhihammer: I had already read about the Milgram experiments, as well as follow-up confirmation experiments. I still disagree with the use of the word "make", because none of them were stripped of their free choice. Many freely chose to do something that I (and presumably you) consider to be morally wrong. The authoritarian influence does not lessen their own moral culpability. Maybe *you* didn't read the experiments carefully enough, because the results clearly showed that a small minority stuck to **their own moral principles** and refused to continue the experiment.

Comment: @user21820 That is your interpretation which is also founded on the belief in free will. Free choice is highly disputed by many. It is neither possible to confirm nor deny your interpretation.

Comment: @bodhihammer: That's fine. We both agree that it is impossible to confirm or deny my interpretation. =) But I'll note that if you do not believe in some form of free will then your comment in which you use the phrase "against their will" is inconsistent.

Comment: @user21820 However, if there is no free choice, then 'the rifle made a bullet strike a hole' and 'the boss made you conduct a report' are quite frankly analogous.

Comment: @bodhihammer: Yes, but as I said, your use of the phrase "against their will" makes your comment inconsistent with "no free choice".

Comment: @user21820 No, 'will' is not the same as 'free will'. See Dennett on free will.

Comment: @bodhihammer: Oh, if you don't want to use the phrase to mean what it does in standard English, you should have said so...

Comment: @user21820 I do nothing of sorts. I express the possibility of will that one can have. All definitions of 'will' from the dictionary deem to imply simply "determining" the course of events.

Comment: @bodhihammer: Read [TheFreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/against+their+will)... Maybe you're not a native speaker. But I am.

Comment: @user21820 Against one's will nowhere implies that individual has 'free choice'. It is not synonymous with 'against one's free will' because there is no synonymy in terms of 'will' and 'free will' as they do not corefer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not interested in useless hair-splitting. You can think what you like (or maybe you think that you have no control over your own thoughts).

Comment: @user21820 Sorry. Either you are logically coherent or not. The synonymy between 'free will' and 'will' does not preserve the same truth-value for all the propositions. You are also missing the point because it is possible to have a control mechanism without having any freedom.

Comment: I never said "free will" = "will". You are the one who misinterpreted. The dictionary clearly shows that "against one's will" is a fixed idiomatic phrase. If you do not understand that idioms are lexical units that cannot be broken down into their constituent words, then I have nothing to say. I will not respond any further if you insist on your interpretation of this basic English idiom. (And I never said it's impossible to have a control mechanism without freedom. Again, that is some interpretation you made up of my comments...)

Answer (score 2):

A belief system is a tool, like a hammer. Some people use it to build a house, some people use it to kill their spouse (ugh, that's way too 'Dr Seuss'...).  Most belief systems ***intend*** to make people's lives better by giving them common rules, common goals, and common standards to live by. But the nature of the egoic mind is that many people are highly motivated to have what's better for themselves, but not overly interested in what's better for others.

How belief systems are used by individuals is a developmental issue that's out of scope for this answer, but we should all be aware (metaphorically) that the difference between an angel and a demon isn't that they have different belief systems, but that they understand their in-common belief system in completely different ways. As I heard a monk quip once: "Everyone goes to the same place when they die, but according to their attitude some think it's heaven and some think it's hell." But you don't need to die to see that effect in practice; it's all around us in the living world.

Comment: «Everyone goes to the same place...some think it's heaven and some think it's hell» 

Answer (score 0):

To argue that belief systems have no influence on the actions of their adherents seems obviously false to me.

Lets choose a non controversial example. You would be arguing that people who don't like pork convert to Islam in order to have an excuse not to eat pork and people who like pork convert to Christianity in order to eat it guilt free.

Given we admit some influence of the belief system on the believer, why would we exclude influence where the things promoted by the belief system are considered evil by some other people?

Undoubtedly there must be some instances of people pretending to a belief to justify their actions or simply taking advantage of a belief for personal gain. But to say it applies in all cases seems ridiculous.